# Why is Central European Time not in common_timezones?

Tags: python, pytz

Why is US Eastern time in `common_timezones`, but Central European Time is not?

```
>>> import pytz

>>> 'US/Eastern' in pytz.common_timezones
True

>>> 'CET' in pytz.common_timezones
False
```

Specifically, should the fact `"CET"` is **not** in `common_timezones` indicate something to me I should be aware of?

Or perhaps more specifically, does `"CET"`'s offset change relative to UTC like `US/Eastern` does when DST is in effect?

Comment: The documentation for pytz (https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) mentions US/Eastern as an exception: "common_timezones is a list of useful, current timezones. It doesn’t contain deprecated zones or historical zones, except for a few I’ve deemed in common usage, such as US/Eastern"

Comment: @Omer ah, ok, that's useful, thanks.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time): "As of 2011, all member states of the European Union observe summer time".

Answer (score 1):

`pytz.common_timezones` is not the same as `pytz.all_timezones`. `CET` is in `all_timezones`

Timezones which are **NOT** in `common_timezones` but are in `all_timezones` are:

```
>>> pprint(sorted(set(pytz.all_timezones) - set(pytz.common_timezones)))
['Africa/Asmera',
 'Africa/Timbuktu',
 'America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia',
 'America/Atka',
 'America/Buenos_Aires',
 'America/Catamarca',
 'America/Coral_Harbour',
 'America/Cordoba',
 'America/Ensenada',
 'America/Fort_Wayne',
 'America/Indianapolis',
 'America/Jujuy',
 'America/Knox_IN',
 'America/Louisville',
 'America/Mendoza',
 'America/Montreal',
 'America/Porto_Acre',
 'America/Rosario',
 'America/Santa_Isabel',
 'America/Shiprock',
 'America/Virgin',
 'Antarctica/South_Pole',
 'Asia/Ashkhabad',
 'Asia/Calcutta',
 'Asia/Chongqing',
 'Asia/Chungking',
 'Asia/Dacca',
 'Asia/Harbin',
 'Asia/Istanbul',
 'Asia/Kashgar',
 'Asia/Katmandu',
 'Asia/Macao',
 'Asia/Rangoon',
 'Asia/Saigon',
 'Asia/Tel_Aviv',
 'Asia/Thimbu',
 'Asia/Ujung_Pandang',
 'Asia/Ulan_Bator',
 'Atlantic/Faeroe',
 'Atlantic/Jan_Mayen',
 'Australia/ACT',
 'Australia/Canberra',
 'Australia/LHI',
 'Australia/NSW',
 'Australia/North',
 'Australia/Queensland',
 'Australia/South',
 'Australia/Tasmania',
 'Australia/Victoria',
 'Australia/West',
 'Australia/Yancowinna',
 'Brazil/Acre',
 'Brazil/DeNoronha',
 'Brazil/East',
 'Brazil/West',
 'CET',
 'CST6CDT',
 'Canada/Saskatchewan',
 'Canada/Yukon',
 'Chile/Continental',
 'Chile/EasterIsland',
 'Cuba',
 'EET',
 'EST',
 'EST5EDT',
 'Egypt',
 'Eire',
 'Etc/GMT',
 'Etc/GMT+0',
 'Etc/GMT+1',
 'Etc/GMT+10',
 'Etc/GMT+11',
 'Etc/GMT+12',
 'Etc/GMT+2',
 'Etc/GMT+3',
 'Etc/GMT+4',
 'Etc/GMT+5',
 'Etc/GMT+6',
 'Etc/GMT+7',
 'Etc/GMT+8',
 'Etc/GMT+9',
 'Etc/GMT-0',
 'Etc/GMT-1',
 'Etc/GMT-10',
 'Etc/GMT-11',
 'Etc/GMT-12',
 'Etc/GMT-13',
 'Etc/GMT-14',
 'Etc/GMT-2',
 'Etc/GMT-3',
 'Etc/GMT-4',
 'Etc/GMT-5',
 'Etc/GMT-6',
 'Etc/GMT-7',
 'Etc/GMT-8',
 'Etc/GMT-9',
 'Etc/GMT0',
 'Etc/Greenwich',
 'Etc/UCT',
 'Etc/UTC',
 'Etc/Universal',
 'Etc/Zulu',
 'Europe/Belfast',
 'Europe/Nicosia',
 'Europe/Tiraspol',
 'GB',
 'GB-Eire',
 'GMT+0',
 'GMT-0',
 'GMT0',
 'Greenwich',
 'HST',
 'Hongkong',
 'Iceland',
 'Iran',
 'Israel',
 'Jamaica',
 'Japan',
 'Kwajalein',
 'Libya',
 'MET',
 'MST',
 'MST7MDT',
 'Mexico/BajaNorte',
 'Mexico/BajaSur',
 'Mexico/General',
 'NZ',
 'NZ-CHAT',
 'Navajo',
 'PRC',
 'PST8PDT',
 'Pacific/Johnston',
 'Pacific/Ponape',
 'Pacific/Samoa',
 'Pacific/Truk',
 'Pacific/Yap',
 'Poland',
 'Portugal',
 'ROC',
 'ROK',
 'Singapore',
 'Turkey',
 'UCT',
 'US/Aleutian',
 'US/East-Indiana',
 'US/Indiana-Starke',
 'US/Michigan',
 'US/Samoa',
 'Universal',
 'W-SU',
 'WET',
 'Zulu']
```

All common timezones are "official" names in the form Region[/Region]/City + of course GMT and UTC as separate entries. Of course not all names in that format are commonly used, as you can see in the list above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of `all_timezones`. My question was more to the fact that `CET` is a very common timezone (as in, the whole of central Europe) and therefore I would have expected it to be in `common_timezones`. @Omer's comment on my question points to the reason it's not